# How to expand node added to TreeView of hidden Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, expand

c# windows forms App-based software is under development.
The problem is that the node I added to the TreeView control is not expanded.

The execution procedure is as follows.

1. Execute winform with Opacity = 0, ShowInTaskbar = false
2. Add a node to the TreeView control in the winform and then expand the node (TreeView.ExpandAll)
3. Show winform with system tray icon
   Issue: The TreeView control's nodes are shrunk.

The solution I found is
After displaying the winform at startup ('Opacity=1') or executing with'ShowInTaskbar=true', adding a node to the TreeView control and expanding it works fine.

I'm new to C#, which keeps using only MFC, but I can't understand this behavior. Is there a more vivid solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This happens if you cause the Form to recreate its Handle. As setting `ShowInTaskbar` to a different value. Changing the `Opacity` property doesn't (it's a call to `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.